# Why does response.write appear to block my browser in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, blocking

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/2-webtail-nodejs-child-processes-and-http-chunked-encoding.html#video

The following code works

```
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

http.createServer(
function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'text/plain'
    });
    var tail_child = spawn('tail', ['-f', 'temp.txt']);

    request.connection.on('end', function () {
        tail_child.kill();
    });

    tail_child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        response.end(data.toString());

    });

}).listen(9000);
```

However the browser does not receive updates to temp.txt.  If I replace

```
response.end(data.toString());
```

with

```
response.write(data.toString());
```

It appears to block and nothing is rendered in the browser.

Edit: I would like the browser to continuously display any appends to the text file in real time as per the tutorial

Comment: I have made an edit to clarify

Comment: Yes, because if you never call `response.end()` the response is never sent.

Comment: In the tutorial there is no response.end() yet new appends appear to 'stream' into the browser

Comment: Welll, perhaps I have missed something; I'm by no means a node expert. I have played around with it and once forgot to call `end()`.   The response was never sent.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using curl instead to test out transfer-encoding: chunked. A lot of web browsers won't render the content in chunks, probably because it isn't really efficient to render HTML in that fashion. If you put enough data into the response eventually the browser may start rendering it as you'd expect though, but it isn't a solution I'd use normally.

If you want to stream data to a web browser in the way you're hoping, I'd use websockets or possibly an ajax call made to your streaming page that would render html as it comes, since an ajax call should fire events for each chunk.

Comment: I've tested this out, and the code in the original question works fine with `response.write()` if you include the `'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'` header and push enough data in. Try adding much more data `temp.txt` using `less temp.txt >> temp.txt`. I also added `'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'`, but not sure whether that made a difference.